# let log4j log on both console and file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to print log4j to both console and logfile, i have the following log4j.properties file:

```
 # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,WARN,INFO,ERROR file, stdout


# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\jeff\\logfile.txt
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I use the Logger in the simple way:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
logger.warn("my message");
```

The logging works perfectly fine on console but not in the file, actually i believe that the cfg file isnt read at all, note that the log4j.poperties file is in the root directory of the project.
In various tutorials i have read that is necessary that log4j.properties is in the classpath, there is no need to manually register it from java code.
Any advice on how can i tell my logger to read the properties from the cfg file?

Comment: You can find information about Java classpath on the [oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to beat me, I am running away... :-)

You **missed a comma** in between ERROR and file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,WARN,INFO,ERROR file, stdout
```

Comment: Also, only one level can be specified not multiple. By using "DEBUG,WARN,INFO,ERROR" it will think the level is DEBUG and that WARN, INFO, ERROR are appenders which will throw an error at runtime.

Comment: OK... and in fact I do get three errors about: e.g.: log4j: ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.WARN log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "WARN".  I think your point is that there can only be one level-- and that the higher levels are included automatically. So getting rid of WARN, INFO, and ERROR will not mean that they will not show up. I.E. putting DEBUG means that everything goes to both the Console and the log file.